WordPress Version 6.6 facing "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed." which edit text on page with link
Today, when I edit a page with text that has link attached to it getting this error "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.".
Same issue when I try to attach new URL/link to text in page.
There has been no changes to plugins.
Version 6.6
Checking as advised in Chrome debug tools (three dots menu, more tools, developer tools, console) got the following messages when click to edit hyperlinked text on WordPress page:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')
at link-format-block.js?ver=4.1.5.3:2:16593
at q (link-format-block.js?ver=4.1.5.3:2:17022)
at hu (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:60308)
at xi (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:119597)
at bs (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:108749)
at vs (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:108677)
at gs (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:108540)
at as (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:105347)
at is (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:105736)
at Hl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:46663)
Also got the following prior messages:
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 wp.editPost.PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem instead.
i @ deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2Understand this warning
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 wp.editPost.PluginSidebar is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginSidebar instead.
i @ deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2Understand this warning
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 wp.editPost.PluginDocumentSettingPanel is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginDocumentSettingPanel instead.
i @ deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2Understand this warning
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 wp.editPost.PluginPrePublishPanel is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginPrePublishPanel instead.
i @ deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2Understand this warning
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 wp.editPost.PluginPostPublishPanel is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginPostPublishPanel instead.
i @ deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2Understand this warning
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 anchorRef prop in wp.components.Popover is deprecated since version 6.1. Please use anchor prop instead.
Not sure what is happening.
BTW, I did try edge & firefox browsers also...but same issue when clicking on any hyperlinked text on page in edit mode. A workaround is to create the text with hyperlink in any editor (Openoffice) and then paste in the web page. However, cannot format links to open in new window - as was possible earlier in WordPress.
Thank you.

I'm guessing this is server side. Please have a look for an error in either 1) your WordPress debug.log under wp-content if you've enabled it, 2) your web server's error log, 3) your php-fpm error log if you're running that. When you find it please edit it into the question. It's also worth looking in your browser's JavaScript debug console for errors too in case there's something there as well.

Thank you for the response.
However, did try enabling debugging in wp-config.php file but it does not seem to be working as no debug.log (under wp-content) is getting generated when I get the error.
BTW, I'm using XAMPP. Did check the error logs in Apache web server in XAMPP console but do not find any error entry for today. I'm using Chrome browser.

Thanks, apologies I was wrong. So this is client side and not in response to a server error (I'd guessed from the oEmbed code). Is there anything in Chrome debug tools then? (three dots menu, more tools, developer tools, console)

Thank you. I did try edge & firefox browsers also...but same issue when clicking on any hyperlinked text on page in edit mode. A workaround is to create the text with hyperlink in any editor (Openoffice) and then paste in the web page. However, cannot format links to open in new window - as was possible earlier in WordPress.

From Chrome, got this from console.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')
at link-format-block.js?ver=4.1.5.3:2:16593
at q (link-format-block.js?ver=4.1.5.3:2:17022)
at hu (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:60308)
at xi (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:119597)
at bs (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:108749)
at vs (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:108677)
at gs (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:108540)
at as (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:105347)
at is (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:105736)
at Hl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.3.1:2:46663)

Got many such messages also...
wp.components.Popover is deprecated since version 6.1. Please use anchor prop instead.
wp.editPost.PluginPostPublishPanel is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginPostPublishPanel instead.
wp.editPost.PluginPrePublishPanel is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginPrePublishPanel instead.
deprecated.min.js?ver=e1f84915c5e8ae38964c:2 wp.editPost.PluginDocumentSettingPanel is deprecated since version 6.6. Please use wp.editor.PluginDocumentSettingPanel instead.

Thanks. They don’t mean anything to me sorry but might to someone else. Can you edit them into the question please? They’ll be easier to read there than in comments.

Done. Thank you for your guidance and support on this. Appreciate it.

Do you have the All in One SEO plugin enabled? Try to disable it and check if the error persists.

First, update your plugins, as chances are at least one of them is old and not compatible with 6.6. If that doesn't fix the issue, deactivate plugins one-by-one until the error goes away - and you'll have found the offender.

Yes, after disabling "All in One SEO plugin" the issue was resolved. Thank you.

Great! Please raise this with All in One SEO as a bug if you haven’t already. It’s probably worth posting that as an answer below too, in case someone else has the same problem.
